# Show date in a href element

Tags: jquery, html

How can I add a date with jquery in the element below:

```
<li><a href="Search.php?DestinationId=A99O&roomsno=1&city=Antalya&In=2015-05-01&Out=2015-05-08">Antalya</a></li>
```

I need that In value to be 30 days from today and Out to be 28 days from today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `$('selector').attr('href')` attribute to get
- add *in* and *out* date with [javascript Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- finally, update the link with `$('selector').attr('href', new_link)`.

Done.

#### Update: Full explanation:

```
function format_date(date){
    return date.getFullYear()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getDate();
}
$('a[href^="Search.php"]').each(function(id, el){
    day_in_offset = 30;
    day_out_offset = 38;
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    in_date = new Date();
    time = in_date.getTime();
    in_date.setTime(time + day_in_offset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    out_date = new Date();
    out_date.setTime(time + day_out_offset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    href += "&In="+format_date(in_date);
    href += "&Out="+format_date(out_date);

    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Comment: sorry but i cant understand.